# How can I force a specific dependency to use specific version of a library in gradle

Tags: android, gradle

I have a dependency `'com.liferay.mobile:liferay-screens:2.1.4'` and I want to force it for example to use `'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'`.
How can I do this force only for `liferay-screens` dependency in gradle?

I've done it like below but it takes error:

`ERROR: Could not find method com.liferay.mobile:liferay-screens:2.1.4() for arguments [build_e4u81lzxji4bi1lau20a1sng2$_run_closure3$_closure7@2be4e1d1] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.`

```
implementation 'com.liferay.mobile:liferay-screens:2.1.4' {
    resolutionStrategy.force 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
}
```

Comment: You **can't** do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Gradle 6.0, my recommendation would be to use the new [`strictly` semantics](https://docs.gradle.org/6.0/userguide/dependency_downgrade_and_exclude.html#sec:enforcing_dependency_version) in a `constraint`:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.liferay.mobile:liferay-screens:2.1.4'
    constraints {
        implementation('com.android.support:support-v4') {
            version {
                strictly '28.0.0' // Will make sure that library uses that version in your build
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Prior to Gradle 6.0, your way would be the recommended one, but the syntax needs to be adapted:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.liferay.mobile:liferay-screens:2.1.4'
}
configurations.all {
    // Will force that dependency version everywhere
    resolutionStrategy.force 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
}
```

There is effectively no point in *forcing* a version *only* in a given context, as you tried to express. What matters is that you want to overall resolution to always use that specific version.